# Авторизация нескольких устройств

Tags: oauth, авторизация

I. Есть веб приложение, с которым работают с десктопа. Вход в него чаще всего без логина/пароля — через аккаунт Google, Facebook и пр.

II. Есть вспомогательное мобильное приложение, которое нужно только для загрузки файлов в аккаунт, используемый с десктопа.

**Как правильно и удобно «перенести» разрешение с десктопа на мобильный?**

Мой вариант пока — OAuth 2.0 в таком сценарии:

1. на десктопе владелец генерит одноразовый токен, короткий, живущий недолго. Напр. "iDdQd", и действует он всего 1 час;
2. этот код нужно ввести в мобильном приложении, которое обменяет его у сервера приложения на более долго живущий токен, который запомнит внутри, и который позволяет только загружать файлы в основной аккаунт.

Таким образом можно дать аккаунту юзера **Б** разрешение загружать файлы в аккаунт юзера **А**; не «светить» на мобильном пароли в Google / Facebook или др. сервис, использованный для базовой авторизации.

Слабое место здесь передача этого одноразового токена: нужно его ввести, не ошибиться, не потерять, ввести вовремя.

Есть ли более удачные схемы авторизации?

Comment: в чем проблема авторизоваться гуглем или фейсбуком на моб устройстве?

Comment: В варианте когда разрешение дается Васе — нужно заранее знать, какой там у него аккаунт. А так - короткий код и всё.

Comment: Мне кажется проще формализовать электронную доставку токена. по почте слать ссылку, например. вбивать любые коды на моб устройстве неудобно, тем более одноразовые, которые не реально запомнить. вбивать с бумажки - не 21 век.  

-----
Ну это кроме варианта реализации правильной полноценной авторизации аккаунта Б на моб устройстве, для которого будет возможность узнать куда он может заливать файлы. Типа: "Вася, зарегайся/авторизуйся, я тебе дам доступ по твоему логину/мылу".